# Open activity in Xamarin Droid UITest

Tags: xamarin, ui-testing, xamarin.uitest

I've started using the Xamarin UITest to verify the behaviour of my application. I wanted to make the tests logically separated (by that I mean, if one test fails the other one should not fail because of the first, they should be independent). My application has multiple activities and I could not find in the documentation how to open a specific Activity.

The closest I could find was:

```
[SetUp]
public void BeforeEachTest()
{
    app = ConfigureApp.Android.LaunchableActivity("MyActivity").StartApp ();
}
```

But nothing happend. Can I do this? Is there a workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A very late response but thought i'd put it up for others to find. In order to launch the app using a specific activity UITest requires two pieces of information, the app name (or APK file path) and the activity name.

Calling StartApp() on the AndroidConfigurator will look as follows for an app that is already installed onto the device or emulator:

```
app = ConfigureApp
    .Android
    .InstalledApp("packagename")
    .LaunchableActivity("activityname")
    .StartApp();
```

Or as follow for an APK file:

```
app = ConfigureApp
    .Android
    .ApkFile("filename")
    .LaunchableActivity("activityname")
    .StartApp();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
if (platform == Platform.Android)
{
    string currentFile = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath;
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(currentFile);
    string dir = fi.Directory.Parent.Parent.Parent.FullName;
    var PathToAPK = Path.Combine(dir, "LetsGetNative.Droid", "bin", "Debug", "LetsGetNative.Droid.apk");
    app = ConfigureApp.Android.ApkFile(PathToAPK).WaitTimes(new WaitTimes()).EnableLocalScreenshots().StartApp();
}
else
{
    app = ConfigureApp.iOS.StartApp();
}
```

Comment: i don't think you understood my question. I want to open an activity that is not the launch one, your code just starts it normally

Comment: You could set your activity you would like to test as `Launch Activity`? Have you tried putting break points in your `MyActivity`? Your code looks fine

Comment: This solution is not good, because for each screen test I wanted to do I would have to change the launch screen, and I'd also have to keep changing code to run the original project. Tests should not interfere with the code